# does querying a list of entities from database loads the entities into managed context in jpa?

Tags: database, jpa, entitymanager, data-persistence

for example:
1.I have 100 entities in a database
2.when i select all those 100 entities via select query,will those entities be loaded to managed context?
3.If yes , what happens if we dont change any attribute values of those entities,will it be committed again to the database after flush method gets called?

Comment: (2) yes (3) if no changes have been made, most (if not all) JPA implementations will not issue any updates to the DB

Comment: would not the loaded entities needs to be stored back to database even if their attributes are not changed?

Comment: sorry i might be asking basic question , but i am new to entity manager concept.

Comment: Why would you think they need to be stored? JPA implementations either keep track of any change you make to an entity, or 'remember' the original state the entity was in right after being loaded into the context. If no changes are detected at persist time, no updates are issued to the DB